# Groovy parallel iteration over two lists

Tags: python, groovy, iteration

Is there any way in groovy to iterate over two lists in parallel in a way so simple and elegant as in Python - `for i in zip(list1, list2):`?

Comment: have you looked here http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Python

Comment: Got it, the key is to use eachWithIndex(), interesting!  Groovy closures still have much expressing power, also in comparison with python...impressed.

Comment: yep, I never have used groovy but I imagine the dict zip example could to be modified quite easily.

Comment: Thanks very much, the dict example was perfect. I have been using groovy closures for months, but they still have many unknown aspects. Bye

Comment: You can also use zip in the groovy-stream extension https://github.com/timyates/groovy-stream/blob/master/src/test/java/groovy/stream/StreamUnitTests.java#L146

Comment: Sorry, that was a Java test, the groovy one is here: https://github.com/timyates/groovy-stream/blob/master/src/test/groovy/groovy/stream/ZipTests.groovy